# Multinomial Naive bayes giving wrong result

Tags: machine-learning, python, scikit-learn, naive-bayes-classifier

```
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB,MultinomialNB
xx = [[1],[1],[1],[2],[2],[3]]
yy = [1,1,1,0,0,0]
clf = GaussianNB()
# clf = MultinomialNB()
clf.fit(xx,yy)
clf.predict(xx)
```

The expected result is [1,1,1,0,0,0]
but code output is [0,0,0,0,0,0].

Comment: Check the regularization parameter--that's often the problem with questions like these. If it's too high, this can happen.

Comment: @SheridanGrant you mean alpha parameter for Laplace smoothing right. the default value for it is 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is only one feature for `xx`.

For a `MultinomialNB`, the modelled probability of the feature per class $p(x_i|y)$ is always the same ($\frac{3}{3}=1$ for class $1$ and $\frac{7}{7}=1$ for class $0$). The prediction is therefore the class prior $p(y_i)$ which is also the same here ($p(0) = 0.5$ and $p(1)=0.5$) so by default class $0$. Having one feature does not really makes sense because it gives no information to the model on what gives discriminative power toward the classes.

For a `GaussianNB` this is different because the modelled probability is given by $P(x_i \mid y) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2_y}} \exp\left(-\frac{(x_i - \mu_y)^2}{2\sigma^2_y}\right)$ so the mean and variance per class of the single feature give sufficient information.